# get "lerna list" output imperatively via lerna api

Tags: lerna, monorepo

I wanna get `lerna list --json` CLI functionality within a node script for various publishing tweaks. I was skimming through the codebase but was not able to find the appropriate API to do the right job:

**Example:**

```
// process-monorepo-packages.js

const {listApi} = require('@lerna/some-package')

const packagesMetadata = listApi({json:true})

// TODO process packagesMetadata
function processPackages(){ /* ... */ }
```

Answer (score 3):

I've tried `@lerna/list` but did not have any luck from there.

A workaround will be using the `child_process` module to spawn a shell and run the command within that shell, then query the names of all packages from what it returns.

```js
const {execSync} = require('child_process');

let output

try {
  output = execSync(`npx lerna ls --json`)
} catch (error) {
  console.info(`No local packages found.`)
  process.exit(0)
}

const packages = JSON.parse(output.toString()); // this will contain the list of the packages
```